# Traceback when using pandas.Series.str.split: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe looks like this, I want to create 5 additional columns by splitting the `key` column with  `_` as separator

```
                                             key   value
VALUETIME                                               
2021-12-17 11:00:00   BE_G_av_211214170724_a  5312.0
2021-12-17 12:00:00   BE_G_av_211214170724_a  5312.0
2021-12-17 13:00:00   BE_G_av_211214170724_a  5312.0
2021-12-17 14:00:00   BE_G_av_211214170724_a  5312.0
2021-12-17 15:00:00   BE_G_av_211214170724_a  5312.0
                                         ...     ...
2022-02-15 06:00:00  NL_G_gen_211205212740_a  3804.0
2022-02-15 07:00:00  NL_G_gen_211205212740_a  5260.0
2022-02-15 08:00:00  NL_G_gen_211205212740_a  6043.0
2022-02-15 09:00:00  NL_G_gen_211205212740_a  6184.0
```

I tried all the below

```
df_a_ccgt_m_fc_long[['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']] = df_a_ccgt_m_fc_long['key'].str.split('_')

df_a_ccgt_m_fc_long[['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']] = df_a_ccgt_m_fc_long['key'].str.split(pat = '_')
```

But both give me the same traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1712, in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path
    "Must have equal len keys and value "

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that by adding `expand=True` it solves my problem, even though I am not sure why, as it seems my data always have 4 `_` and don't have any missing data in the 5 parts.

Comment: Without `expand=True` you only get 1 column (containing lists of strings) which is why you get the error. You cannot assign 1 column to 4 columns in this way.